# Usage of "so (that)"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Is this correct to use "so (that)" this way if not then can you explain please?

We need a volunteer to help us (This one is correctly).

Can we say that one this way?

> We need a volunteer so that he can help us

Comment: It's difficult to explain why your version doesn't sound right. We don't need to say that the reason for needing a volunteer is 'so that they can help', because that's what a volunteer does. However, if the reason for doing or needing something is less obvious, 'so that' can introduce the explanation.

Comment: @KateBunting But if it is question like: Why do we need volunteer? And can it be respond by starting with this?: "So that he can help us"

Comment: @KateBunting or it's incorrect anyway

Comment: Your version isn't grammatically wrong, it just seems to me less idiomatic. As I said, the reason is hard to explain. I would expect the question "Why do we need a volunteer?" to be answered with something more specific, like "Because we haven't enough staff" or "To help with the packing".